# What mean of the Schema in a table design?

Tags: database-design

When I use DbWrench design my table, there is a option named: Schema, and it only has one option: `SchemaA`.

[image]

What that mean, and how does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, "schema" means two things in the context of databases

1. "The" schema is the design of the database. "Show me the database schema". Usually this means they want a diagram showing the tables and foreign keys
2. "A" schema is like a namespace. This allows you to have different items with the same name in the same database. For example, there's an existing function in PostgreSQL called `split_part()` but you could write your own and call it `my_schema.split_part()` Schemas can also make it easy to manage permissions in a bulk manner

Oracle calls its schemas "users". MySQL, confusingly, calls its schemas "databases". Everyone else calls their schemas "schemas". Some databases don't use schemas

Answer (score 0):

> A database schema of a database system is its structure described in a formal language supported by the database management system (DBMS).

A schema can contains multiple database, but not means every database user can access the schema's contents, this called permissions.

[image]

Through the upper image, User1 can access Schema1 Schema3, can not access Schema2.

In brief, the schema can create permission to access the data of database.